# How to extend robot-ide (RIDE) to have a tab so that I can drag and drop robot script commands?

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am trying to extend RIDE to have some custom functionality like an extra tab which can hold some diagram with commands (commands editable) and these can be drag and dropped to the right side to have a flow chart which will have the robot script commands.

I have downloaded RIDE source code https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE.
I am relatively new to python programming. Could you please help me get started with this. Any tutorial/pdf related to this will be helpful for me?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is far too broad for stackoverflow. You should maybe ask on the robotframework slack channel or the [robot framework forum](https://forum.robotframework.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the project page's Wiki, there should be some useful information.

The best approach is to create a standalone program outside of RIDE, and later adapt to be used as a Plugin.

Most important is to learn wxPython, and for that is **mandatory** to at least run its Demo.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am starting with wxPython. Actually I am not able to find the wiki of RIDE codes, not even documentation which guides to run the code locally. Currently I am running src/bin/ride.py to get the RIDE ui to edit the code. It would be nice if you can put forward some link for this!

Comment: You have to look better on https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE